# IntelliSense completely covers cursor in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2022

When typing in Visual Studio 2022 the IntelliSense popup almost always obscures the cursor making typing difficult.  Is there a way to adjust this?  I tried resetting all settings to default but it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any kind of monitor scaling enabled through Windows? What happens if at the same location as the cursor you do CTRL + Space?

Comment: The monitor scaling is what was causing it.  Thanks.  Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your monitor/display scaling.  UI issues like this can often be due to that.

In Windows, you can do this via the Display settings:

[image: windows display scaling options]

Comment: I have this same issue, but my scaling is correct... set to 100%, any other solutions?

Comment: @dkimbell13 not too sure. Maybe try changing the scale to something like 150% for a second and then changing back to 100?

Comment: LOL, Turning it off and back on worked!

Comment: @dkimbell13 guess I should add that to my answer ;)